# Jacobian elliptic function argument

Tags: special-functions

I have a `C++` code that computes jacobian elliptic `sn`, `cn` and `dn`. This code is from `GSL library`.

[github source cpp file](https://github.com/ekato993/ellipt/blob/main/ellipt.cpp)

```
void elipticjacobi(double u, double m, double * sn, double * cn, double * dn) {
    if(fabs(m) > 1.0) {
        *sn = 0.0;
        *cn = 0.0;
        *dn = 0.0;
        //error code
    }
    ....
}
```

If I calculate `sn(2,0.2)` with my code, and if I calculate `sn(2,0.2)` with WolframAlpha I am getting the same result and the result is `0.953667`.

The elliptic function second argument must be `|m|<1` but if I calculate `sn(2,4)` with WolframAlpha I am getting `-0,29`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: [Analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation)? `Plot[JacobiSN[2, m], {m, -4, 4}]` shows no such restriction on $m$.

Comment: Possibly, the source of the discrepancy is the normalization of the functions .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions solely about Wolfram|Alpha are not appropriate.